# Is there a column type that supports both internal and external links?

Tags: custom-field-types, url, hyperlink

I'm creating a custom list as part of a solution. The list items are then rendered via a visual webpart which also exists in the solution. The webpart is designed to allow a user to maintain a list of links that are then rendered on screen. The links however can be either internal or external. Is there an inbuilt field type to support this or do I have to roll my own in order to generate an internal content picker or public url field whenever the item is being populated?

One thing I should clarify is that I'm aware of the SPFieldUrl type. What I'm looking for is for the internal url / content picker to display the content picker dialog to navigate to the content when it is an internal link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog known is a special customization of what is known as an AssetPicker, and this one comes with Publishing Sites because is actually part of Publishing controls (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.asseturlselector(v=office.14).aspx)

You can either :

1. Use this one in code (add publishing assembly to your code) or as a
   column (available as you shall activate Publishing infrastructure
   features at Site Collection and Web )
2. Build your own custom field and override AssetPicker to behave otherwise, see here http://www.theroks.com/custom-asset-picker-with-enhanced-urlfield/

Comment: Excellent! I had a feeling I'd have to roll my own but didn't realise someone had covered it in detail. Thanks, that'll save me some time. :-)